# Bootstrap 4 vertical align bottom for a div inside a jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've seen lots of answers about middle vertical alignment, but I can't find one for bottom alignment of a div inside of a jumbotron.

```
<section id="profileHero">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid rounded d-flex align-items-end align-bottom">
        <div class="profileHeader rounded p-3">
          <h3 class="display-4">[profile name]</h3>
          <p class="lead">[profile location]</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

I've tried all combinations of align-items-end and align-bottom.  The jumbotron added CSS is:

```
  .jumbotron {
     background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)), url("./assets/images/image.jpg");
     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     max-height: 45vh;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
  }
 .jumbotron img {
    -webkit-filter: none;
  }
 .profileHeader {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* fallback */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* overlay */
    color: white;
  }
```

I'd like to have the profileHeader div snugged down in the lower left corner and then I can move it up and in with ml-2,mb-2 etc.

Comment: try `style="position:absolute;bottom:0;`

Comment: @xNoJustice - that just shrinks the jumbotron down to the size of the div containing the text

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the d-flex class is not working (I've tried display: flex in the console and then it does work), also the vertical align works only when you have extra space in the vertical axis (e.g. if you define a height that is bigger than the content) or if you have more than one element inside the container and their height is different, otherwise the external container adapts to the height of the internal container.